# Show that a continuous function with a certain integral property must be f(x)=x.

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying for the quals in January and am working through the following problem:

> Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function with the property
>   that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)x^n \, \textrm{d}x = \dfrac{1}{n+2}$.
>   Show that $f(x)\equiv x$.

I was thinking to do integration by parts, but this does not seem to yield anything. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: For what range of $n?$

Comment: note that you don't have any assumptions about differentiability so, strictly speaking, integration by parts isn't available to you

Comment: Igor, the question puts no stipulations on the value of $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x) -x$, then
$$
\int g(x)p(x)dx = 0
$$
for every polynomial $p$. Now by Weierstrass Approximation, and the continuity of the integral, it follows that
$$
\int g^2(x)dx = 0
$$
Since $g$ is continuous, it follows that $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: Thank you! My second thought was Weierstass, but I wasn't sure if there was a better route to go.

Comment: Why do we need that integral condition? continuity of $f$ is sufficient to have a fixed point.

Comment: Where does the first line come from?

Comment: @Tojamaru : Not sure what you mean, but the question does not ask for a fixed point, but for $f$ to be identically equal to $x$.

Comment: @Chris : The given condition says that $$\int f(x)x^ndx = \int x\cdot x^ndx$$

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I was thinking that it relied on the fact f(x)=x but it just relies on the fact that if f(x)=x then the integral is the same which is different.

Comment: I misssed it sorry.....then he should have written $f(x)\equiv x$

Answer (score 3):

I would say,
(a) Prove it for $f$ polynomial.
(b) use Stone-Weierstrass to approximate by polynomials, and then use (a) to show that the coefficients other than the linear term are arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this helps...
$$(n+2)\int_0^1f(x)x^ndx=1$$
Then $$\int_0^1(n+2)f(x)x^ndx=1$$
You can see the power rule embedded in there now, except $x^n$ would need to be $x^{n+1}$.  So what must $f(x)$ be?